# jQuery .change() doesn't work with a dropdown

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the jQuery `.change()` method to alert when a dropdown menu changes, unfortunately, it isn't working.

Current code (placed directly above `</body>`):

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#specialism").change(function () {
            alert("Selected value is : ");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Select HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="specialism" id="specialism" required="required">
    <option value="1">Option</option>
</select>
```

Why won't this work? Many thanks!

Comment: How do you change the select when it only has one option ?

Comment: If I open the dropdown and click it, wouldn't that still trigger it?

Comment: Nope, you have to actually change the value, it won't change just because you click the same value once more -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/n9rda2yu/

Comment: How simple, yet so frustrating I missed that. Thank you @adeneo!

Comment: one option won't trigger it, use $("#specialism").on("mouseup", function()) instead.